# Delete Item from specific location in list in Python

Tags: python, menu, indexing

I'm writing a statistics program which will maintain a list of float values. The program will implement the following menu:

1. Add value to list
2. Delete value from list (by value)
3. Delete value from list (by location in list)
4. Display list
5. Exit

I've written everything except the third option. I can't figure out how to get it done. How would one do that?

Comment: How are you currently keeping track of the items in the list?

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can delete an item from a list by referencing it. Like this:

```
del list[location]
```

Comment: or, if you dont want the destroy the original list 

new_list = list[:location] + list[location+1:]